# RegEx to replace certain text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have text from chats containing 200.000+ lines in format like this:

```
[21-Nov-22 04:49 PM] VillagerA
Hi


[21-Nov-22 04:50 PM] VillagerB
Hello


[21-Nov-22 04:50 PM] VillagerA
Hi again


[21-Nov-22 04:51 PM] VillagerB
Hello again
```

*This is just an example. I'm using different names for VillagerA and VillagerB.*

I want to change the format to:

```
VillagerA: Hi
VillagerB: Hello
VillagerA: Hi again
VillagerB: Hello again
```

I've searched for similar questions like this, but I can't understand how to replace some characters using RegEx on Notepad++. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find what: `^.+\] (.+)$\R(.+)\R?\s*$`
- Replace with: `$1: $2`
- Enable `Wrap Around`
- Search mode: `Regular Expression`

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.